# Return argument type uint256[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Return argument type uint256[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Types{
uint[] data;
uint8 j = 0;
function loop() public returns(uint){

    do{
        j++;
    data.push(j);
    }

 while(j < 5);

return data;  //error here
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
returns(uint)
```

This expression states that the function is supposed to return `uint` (an unsigned integer). But the actual code in the function returns `uint[]` (an array of unsigned integers).

**Solution**: Change the `returns` statement to

```
returns(uint[] memory)
```

Which means an array of unsigned integers, and the `memory` keywords is the [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#data-location) of the reference type array.

Comment: now i Get
 Data location can only be specified for array, struct or mapping types, but "memory" was given.

Comment: @Chahat Note the `[]` symbol in my answer, that specifies using an array... In your snippet, the `return data;` returns an array, so you also need declare returning an array.